# Problema al guardar imagen en servidor

Tags: php, android-studio

> PHP subir

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        include('conexion.php');
            //Agregar reporte de marcadores
            $datos[0] = trim($_POST['usuario']);
            $datos[1] = trim($_POST['fecha']);
            $datos[2] = trim($_POST['hora']);
            $datos[3] = trim($_POST['tipo']);
            $datos[4] = trim($_POST['localizacion']);
            $datos[5] = trim($_POST['descripcion']);
            $datos[6] = trim($_POST['imagen']);

            $decodeImage = base64_decode("$datos[6]");
            file_put_contents("pruebas/".datos[0].".JPG", $decodeImage);

                $addReporte = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO reporte (usuario,fecha,hora,tipo,localizacion,obsUsuario) VALUES ('$datos[0]','$datos[1]','$datos[2]','$datos[3]','$datos[4]','$datos[5]')").mysqli_error($con);
                  if ($addReporte != 1) {
                        //problema al registrar reportes
                        echo "problem-report".mysqli_error($con);
                    }else{
                        echo "report_saved";
                    }
        }else{
        echo "Bloqueado por el Administrador";
        }   
     ?>
```

> Android

```
    ImageView Fotografia;
    String base64;
    Fotografia = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap Imagen;

....
```

> Enviar La información

```
HttpClient httpClient;
    HttpPost httpPost;
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpPost = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.registrar_reporte));//url del servidor

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        //empezamos añadir nuestros datos
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario",Preferencias.getString("ID",""))); //ID de usuario logeado
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fecha",Fecha.format(new Date()))); //Fecha de envio
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hora",Hora.format(new Date()))); //Hora de envio
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipo",String.valueOf(Tipo))); //Bache,Iluminaria,....
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("localizacion",Ubicacion)); //Coordenadas GPS
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("descripcion",repDescripcion.getText().toString())); //Descripcion del usuario
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagen",base64)); //Imagen de reporte


        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

        return true;

    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  false;
```

> Boton Enviar

```
Imagen =((BitmapDrawable) Fotografia.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Imagen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
                    base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    new Insertar(Reporte_App.this).execute();
```

> Problema!

No se almacena en el servidor, todo funciona perfecto si le quito

```
$datos[6] = trim($_POST['imagen']);
$decodeImage = base64_decode("$datos[6]");
file_put_contents("pruebas/".datos[0].".JPG", $decodeImage);
```

Todo lo que lleva texto a la bdd se almacena, mi problema es al intentar guardar la imagen.

Comment: ¿Podrías confirmar si tienes permisos de escritura en `./pruebas./` haciendo un `file_put_contents('pruebas/prueba.txt', 'texto de prueba' );`? ¿Podrías comprobar si no es una errata que tengas `file_put_contents("pruebas/". $datos[0] .".JPG", $decodeImage);` sin el dólar (`$datos[0]` sin el `$` delante)?

Comment: ¿Podrías comprobar si tu fallo es un error de sintaxis al no poner el `$` en la variable o comprobar los permisos como te indiqué? Si nos aportas datos adicionales podremos reabrir la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta que el tipo de input que debes utilizar es:

```
<input type="file" name="picture" id="picture"></input>
```

No es por $POST que obtienes los datos del archivo. Esta linea de código esta mal:

```
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
```

En vez de usar $POST usas como en tu linea de código siguiente $_FILES para obtener los datos del archivo que enviastes del formulario. Reemplaza la línea anterior por esta otra:

```
$filename=$_FILES['picture']['name'];
```

Recuerda también que cuando vas a subir un archivo el tipo de encriptación del elemento form  debe ser multipart en el formulario donde envias el archivo. De esta forma:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

**Observación:** Si quieres el tipo de archivo que estas subiendo (sirve mucho para validar que no coloquen .txt cuando sólo quieres es formatos de imágen por ejemplo) utilizas:

```
$tipo_archivo = $_FILES['picture']['type'];
```

Para  el tamaño del archivo es:

```
$tamano_archivo = $_FILES['picture']['size'];
```

Eso es todo. Un saludo!

Comment: intente colocarlo como me dijiste **$filename=$_FILES['picture']['name'];** en POSTMAN me sigue marcando error _Undefined index: picture_

Comment: sin embargo con mi respuesta como esta actualmente deberias ser capaz de obtener el resultado que buscas... Descarga firephp que es una extensión de navegador y usala para "depurar" el envio y recepción de tu documento.

Comment: Agregue todas como quedaría con android, ponle un ojo!